# Сохранить введенный текст в словарь в python kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, framework, kivy

Подскажите как мне при нажатии кнопки "aply" сохранять введенные данные в словарь,первый ТекстИнпут это ключ, второй - значение

```
class TrainApp(App):
    dic = {}

    def build(self):
        al = AnchorLayout()
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical',spacing = 5, size_hint = (.8,.8 ))

        bl.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl.add_widget(TextInput())
        bl.add_widget(Button(text = 'Aply', on_press = self.aply))

        al.add_widget(bl)

        return al

    def aply(self, instance):
        pass
```

Comment: Ошибка синтаксиса, подправьте отступы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Учись сынок)**

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

# размеры окна
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 400)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 200)
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.my_dictionary = None

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, row_force_default=True, 
            row_default_height=40)

        self.key = TextInput(multiline=False, text='Введите ключ')
        self.key.bind(text=self.create_dictionary)

        self.value = TextInput(multiline=False, text='Введите значение')
        self.value.bind(text=self.create_dictionary)

        self.button = Button(text='Распечатать значения словаря', on_press = 
            self.print)
        self.button.disabled = True

        layout.add_widget(Label(text='Создание словаря в Python 3'))
        layout.add_widget(self.key)
        layout.add_widget(self.value)

        layout.add_widget(self.button)

        return layout

    def create_dictionary(self, instance, value):
        self.button.disabled = False
        print(self.key.text, self.value.text)
        self.my_dictionary = {self.key.text: self.value.text}


    def print(self, instance):
        print(self.my_dictionary.items())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```